# Script para validar e padronizar gramática com Panda em Python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, dataframe

boa tarde!

Estou usando Panda no Python para ler algumas planilhas de excel, juntar em uma só e tratar os dados.
Nisso tem uma coluna chamada bairro, onde alguns bairros se repetem porém de formas diferentes(Ex.: centro, Centro, CENTRO, Centro Histórico).
Gostaria de saber como eu poderia percorrer essa coluna e ler todos os elementos que contenham centro, Centro, CENTRO, Centro Histórico e validá-los e padronizá-los para Centro Histórico.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Desde já o meu muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Vou lhe mostrar duas possíveis formas de fazer isso. Vamos tomar como base os dados abaixo:

```py
   endereco  bairro
0  "Rua 1"   "centro "
1  "Rua 2"   " CENTRO"
2  "Rua 3"   "Outro"
3  "Rua 4"   " Centro Histórico"
4  "Rua 5"   "centro histórico"
5  "Rua 6"   "Novo"
6  "Rua 7"   "centro "
7  "Rua 8"   "Outro"
8  "Rua 9"   "Centro"
9  "Rua 10"  "CENTRO"
```

### 1. Usando a função `isin`:

Você pode simplesmente criar uma lista ou tupla e usar o método `isin` para filtrar as linhas desejadas.
Simplesmente podemos usar o sinal de atribuição (`=`) e definir o valor "Centro Histórico":

```py
filtro = ('centro', 'CENTRO', 'Centro')
df['bairro'][df['bairro'].isin(filtro)] = 'Centro Histórico'
```

Porém esse método gera um problema:

```py
>>> df
  endereco             bairro
0    Rua 1            centro 
1    Rua 2             CENTRO
2    Rua 3              Outro
3    Rua 4   Centro Histórico
4    Rua 5   centro histórico
5    Rua 6               Novo
6    Rua 7   Centro Histórico
7    Rua 8              Outro
8    Rua 9   Centro Histórico
9   Rua 10   Centro Histórico
```

Repare que algumas linhas não foram modificadas pois essas possuem espaços em branco que não correspondem ao filtro. Podemos resolver isso removendo os espaços em branco antes:

```py
>>> df['bairro'] = df['bairro'].str.strip()
>>> df['bairro'][df['bairro'].isin(filtro)] = 'Centro Histórico'
>>> df
  endereco            bairro
0    Rua 1  Centro Histórico
1    Rua 2  Centro Histórico
2    Rua 3             Outro
3    Rua 4  Centro Histórico
4    Rua 5  centro histórico
5    Rua 6              Novo
6    Rua 7  Centro Histórico
7    Rua 8             Outro
8    Rua 9  Centro Histórico
9   Rua 10  Centro Histórico
```

Repara que na linha 4 não houve alteração e isso será explorado no próximo método.

### 2. Usando a função `str.contains` com expressão regular:

```py
>>> filtro_regex = r'^\s*(centro|centro histórico)\s*$'
>>> df['bairro'][df.bairro.str.contains(filtro_regex, case=False)] = 'Centro Histórico'
>>> df
endereco            bairro
0    Rua 1  Centro Histórico
1    Rua 2  Centro Histórico
2    Rua 3             Outro
3    Rua 4  Centro Histórico
4    Rua 5  Centro Histórico
5    Rua 6              Novo
6    Rua 7  Centro Histórico
7    Rua 8             Outro
8    Rua 9  Centro Histórico
9   Rua 10  Centro Histórico
```

Explicando a expressão regular:

- `r`: informa ao Python que a string se trata de uma expressão regular.
- `^\s*`: Procura por caracteres de espaço (se houver) no início do valor.
- `(centro|centro histórico)`: informa que deverá procurar por **centro** ou **centro histórico**.
- `\s*$`: Procura por caracteres de espaço (se houver) no final do valor.

Além disso o argumento `case=False` indica que a busca deve ignorar o case, ou seja, não diferenciar caracteres minúsculos ou maiúsculos.